# XMLOutputFactory.newInstance() giving me a NoClassDefFound error

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, saxparser

So here is my function:

```
    public void writeUserToFile() {
    File newXmlFile = new File("res\\SavedShoppers.xml");
    try {
        ArrayList<User> oldUsers = null;
        if(newXmlFile.length() > 0){
            oldUsers = buildUsersFromFile(); // get old users
            // remove current user from old users list to eliminate duplicates
            for (int i = 0; i < oldUsers.size(); i++) {
                if (oldUsers.get(i).equals(this))
                    oldUsers.remove(i);
            }
        }
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newXmlFile);
        XMLStreamWriter out = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
                .createXMLStreamWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
        out.writeStartDocument();
            out.writeStartElement("user");
            out.writeAttribute("userId", String.valueOf(getUserId()));
            out.writeAttribute("name", getName());
            for (ShoppingList sl : getShoppingLists()) {
                out.writeStartElement("shoppingList");
                out.writeAttribute("name", sl.getName());
                for (ListItem li : sl.getItems()) {
                    out.writeStartElement("listItem");
                    out.writeAttribute("name", li.getName());
                    out.writeAttribute("quantity",
                            String.valueOf(li.getQuantity()));
                    out.writeEndElement();
                }
                out.writeEndElement(); // shoppingList
            }
            out.writeEndElement(); // user
        out.writeEndDocument();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is to save a user to an XML file to pull out later. This is for a very simple shopping list app that will create a cart as you shop to help you total up your purchase as you go. Here is the error I'm getting:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory`

As I debug through is happening on this line:

`XMLStreamWriter out = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStrem, "utf-8"))`

And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... I've been working on this for a few days now so I'm out of ideas... any help or direction would be great!

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: It was in my build path. I was using jre7 and had that in my build path, but I also had jer5 in my build path so java was looking for it there instead of 7... and the class doesn't exist in 5.. therefore NoClassDefFound error! :) Yay. Since no one responded, I assume that this is not a common problem so I hope that in the future, someone can find this post when they're searching for the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in my build path. I was using jre7 and had that in my build path, but I also had jer5 in my build path so java was looking for it there instead of 7... and the class doesn't exist in 5.. therefore NoClassDefFound error! :) Yay. Since no one responded, I assume that this is not a common problem so I hope that in the future, someone can find this post when they're searching for the same error!